# API Gateway - how to do case-insensitive request body validation

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've created a model within API Gateway, included regex patterns and enabled request body validation. It all works as expected until I try to perform a case-insensitive match on the regex. For example:

This works:

```
{
  "required" : [ "example_string" ],
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "example_string" : {
      "pattern" : "^([0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{8})$",
      "type" : "string",
      "format" : "example string"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I add the `(?i)` modifier, it is rejected by API gateway:

```
{
  "required" : [ "example_string" ],
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "example_string" : {
      "pattern" : "(?i)^([0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{8})$",
      "type" : "string",
      "format" : "example string"
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> `Invalid model specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid model schema specified]`

Is there any way to perform case insensitive matching without having to specify `[A-Za-Z]`? Whilst I can easily work around it in this case, I also want to perform case insensitive checking of allowed words e.g. `"true|false"`

Comment: Try `[[:xdigit:]]` instead of `[0-9A-Z]`. I.e. `"pattern" : "^[[:xdigit:]]{8}-[[:xdigit:]]{8}-[[:xdigit:]]{8}$"`

Comment: If there is no support for `(?i)` then inline modifiers are not supported and if you have no way to pass the flag, you can't solve the `true|false` issue other than using `[tT][rR][Uu][Ee]|[fF][aA][lL][sS][eE]`

Comment: Seems like API Gateway's JSON schema doesn't yet support (?i). Something about an ECMA 262 only support.